# C# Websocket-Client giving an uninsightful error message

Tags: c#, .net-core, websocket

I have a c# websocket client using https://github.com/Marfusios/websocket-client and it worked just fine, however now after receiving a message it disconnects with the following error:

> 2021-08-24 19:50:58.9833|ERROR|Websocket.Client.WebsocketClient|[WEBSOCKET CLIENT] Exception while connecting. Waiting 60 sec before next reconnection try. Error: 'The operation was canceled.'

What does this mean? I'm clueless as to where to start debugging

Comment: Could be that the server closed the socket - https://github.com/Marfusios/websocket-client/blob/f8e776502abfc61696d13a56f112d9a991a26749/src/Websocket.Client/WebsocketClient.cs#L493

Comment: No, On the server console the log message that appears whenever the client disconnects appears after sending a JSON message